# Como ordenar itens de um list usando dois valores diferentes?

Tags: python, lista, python-2.7, for

Tenho um `list`, que contem vários valores, cada grupo de valores corresponde a um áudio de um idioma, porem não estou conseguindo ordenar usando duas condições.

```
audio_list = [{640: 640, 'lang': u'en', 'language': 'English', 'lang_code': 'en', 'bitrate': 640, 'size': 226600396}, {448: 448, 'lang': u'en', 'language': 'English', 'lang_code': 'en', 'bitrate': 448, 'size': 159037132}, {384: 384, 'lang': u'en', 'language': 'English', 'lang_code': 'en', 'bitrate': 384, 'size': 136516042}, {384: 384, 'lang': u'en', 'language': 'English', 'lang_code': 'en', 'bitrate': 384, 'size': 136516044}, {256: 256, 'lang': u'en', 'language': 'English', 'lang_code': 'en', 'bitrate': 256, 'size': 91473868}, {192: 192, 'lang': u'en', 'language': 'English', 'lang_code': 'en', 'bitrate': 192, 'size': 68952780}, {128: 128, 'lang': u'en', 'language': 'English', 'lang_code': 'en', 'bitrate': 128, 'size': 46431692}, {128: 128, 'lang': u'pt-BR', 'language': 'Brazilian', 'lang_code': 'pt-BR', 'bitrate': 128, 'size': 46431692}, {96: 96, 'lang': u'en', 'language': 'English', 'lang_code': 'en', 'bitrate': 96, 'size': 35171148}, {96: 96, 'lang': u'pt-BR', 'language': 'Brazilian', 'lang_code': 'pt-BR', 'bitrate': 96, 'size': 35171148}]

language = ['pt-BR', 'en']

for idx, language_code in enumerate(language):
    max_audio = audio_list[ idx ]
    lang_bitrate = max_audio.get('bitrate')
    lang_name = max_audio.get('language')
    print(lang_name + " - " + str(lang_bitrate))
```

Quando executo o código acima, obtenho o seguinte resultado:

> English - 640
>
> English - 448

Porem eu deveria obter o seguinte resultado, ordenado pelo tipo de áudio que vier primeiro em `language` e pelo `bitrate`:

> Brazilian - 128
>
> English - 640

Como eu poderia receber o resultado acima, ordenado pelo `bitrate` dos áudios em `audio_list`, e pela ordem do `language` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se eu entendi e/ou implementei corretamente, o resultado será diferente do que voce apresenta, vou ordenar a lista dos dicionarios, ai é só vc adaptar para o seu contexto:

```
# Ordenando
audio_sorted = sorted(audio_list, key=lambda k: (list(k.keys())[0],\
k['language'], k['bitrate']))

# Apresentando os 3 primeiros resultados:
audio_sorted[:3]
[{96: 96,
  'lang': 'pt-BR',
  'language': 'Brazilian',
  'lang_code': 'pt-BR',
  'bitrate': 96,
  'size': 35171148},
 {96: 96,
  'lang': 'en',
  'language': 'English',
  'lang_code': 'en',
  'bitrate': 96,
  'size': 35171148},
 {128: 128,
  'lang': 'pt-BR',
  'language': 'Brazilian',
  'lang_code': 'pt-BR',
  'bitrate': 128,
  'size': 46431692}]
```

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/sortkeys).

**Observação:** 
Voce pode variar as "Keys", para obter o resultado desejado.